# Invalid URL argument

Tags: sharepoint-online, html, mobile

When trying to reach a custom HTML page hosted on sharepoint - this error only occurs when opened on a mobile device / tablet & works perfectly fine on a computer.

> "Sorry something went wrong"...

The only reason i can think this would happen is due to the file name containing "_"

Can anyone share info?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint online won't support browsing HTML pages, that's by design. I am not sure how did it worked while browsing from PC. For me, when i try to browse HTML file it downloads the file in mobile and browser too. If you have new experience applied it will open HTML file in edit mode. The underscore won't be a problem for browsing the page even if you are using the Page Viewer webpart to render HTML page